# How to make standerd application for rendering the live web pages in Computer Desktop application as well as all mobile application?

Tags: desktop-application, mobile-application

I want to make all types of application as a desktop application

- Windows
- Mac
- Linux

I also wants to make all kinds of mobile application

- Android
- BlackBerry OS
- iOS
- Symbian OS
- Java Mobile Application

I am thinking that i will make 1 application and then convert that application for all apps..!

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very generic question. I can only offer a suggestion:
For mobile applications, you can check out Rhodes framework or PhoneGap framework. The following article will give you more idea.

http://www.amlcode.com/2010/07/16/comparison-appinventor-rhomobile-phonegap-appcelerator-webview-and-aml/

For desktops, I could suggest Java as the technology platform.

You can also consider making it a web based application which can be accessed via web browser from any device (desktop/mobile).

JavaFX, with it's latest release 2.0 is also an exciting platform.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX_Mobile

http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/oracle-shows-javafx-ios-and-android-174996

Your choice of technology really should depend on your application's goals and target audience.